# LINQ Query to dynamically filter database where child table column equals optional input value

Tags: entity-framework, linq

So I have a method to dynamically alter a LINQ query based on optional inputs from the user.

```
  var query = from i in _dbContext.Incidents.Include(Incident => Incident.childtable1)
                                  .Include(Incident => Incident.childtable2)
                                  .Include(Incident => Incident.childtable3)
                                  .Include(Incident => Incident.childtable4)
                               
         
                        select i;

            // Append Query to take into account user selection

            query = query.
        if (bool)
            query = query.Where(i => i.column.Equals(userinput));
        if (bool)
            query = query.Where(i => i.column1.Equals(userinput1));
        if (bool)
            query = query.Where(i =>i.column2.Equals(userinput2));
       
            var results = query.ToList();


            return results;
        }
```

However I want to be able to also filter results where the user input matches a column in one of the child tables.

e.g something like

```
 if (bool)
            query = query.Where(i =>i.childtable2.column2.Equals(userinput2));
```

Is there a way to add it to my current method?

Comment: I removed the linq-to-sql tag. That's not EF. Please add a tag for the EF version you use.

Answer (score 2):

In this case you could do something like this:

```
if(condition)
    query = query.Where(i => i.ChildTable2.Any(c => c.Column2 == "foo"));
```